# reset or clear the previous page after navigating

Tags: flutter

I do have a problem with `persistent_bottom_nav_bar` with navigating after the user has successfully created or added a task in to-do-list.
I am using the provided navigate to new screen by the package and I am currently at page `create_task.dart`

```
PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
context,
screen: const HomePage(),
customPageRoute: ,
withNavBar: true, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
);
```

However the problem is that after I navigated to `HomePage` and I go to the `create_task.dart` the inputs and others such as image are still present. I want to navigate to `HomePage` and when I want to go to `create_task.dart` I want page to like fresh/new that I have to fill everything again.

updated:
so I have tried using this Navigator

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
          (_) => false);
```

However, whenever this Navigator triggers. The `HomePage` now replace the `create_task.dart` page. The UI of `create_task.dart` is now gone and now replaced by `HomePage`'s UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to answer this one since I fixed mine already and hopefully might help others who are using `persistent_bottom_nav_bar` package..

Explanation:
So I created a file with the name of `BottomNavigatorHolder.dart`
This includes the [sample codes](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar/example) that can be used to create a bottom nav bar that is provided in the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar).

I have tried their `.pushNewScreen` that they have provided but it does not reset / clear the textfields or inputs of `create_task.dart` whenever I have successfully created a post and redirected to `HomePage` and go back to `create_task.dart`

```
PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
        context,
        screen: HomePage(),
        withNavBar: true, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
        pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
    );
```

Since in the `BottomNavigatorHolder.dart` holds the screen/pages of my UI and it also holds the Bottom Navigators Selections

```
List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
        return [
          HomePage(),
          CreateTask()
        ];
    }
```

I have decided to just clear everything and start everything as a new as if I was just recently logged in.. Here is the [sample code](https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/issues/70#issuecomment-683937549) of navigating, since `HomePage` is the first or index 0 in my `_buildScreens()` it returns or redirects me me to HomePage after I have successfully created/added a post.

PS: I am really sorry. English is my not native and first language, I just wanna answer this one so that maybe someday it might helpful to others.